# Is Google search personalized?

Tags: search

Pardon me if this is a very naive question.

Suppose I search for something on Google and my next-door neighbour searches for the same thing (on Google) at the same time. Do we get the same or different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Google about that, and the second result was:
[Google personalizes search results even when you’re logged out, new study claims](https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/4/18124718/google-search-results-personalized-unique-duckduckgo-filter-bubble)

From there:

> Google says it still personalizes for location and “immediate context from a prior search.”

I don't know exactly how Google personalizes searches (are there any other parameters?), but I'd say it is likely you'd get the same results (because you are both approximately at the same location), while it is also possible that they differ.